# base_url is not working in codeigniter 3.0.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I am using CodeIgniter 3.0.3, and I can't config `base_url()`. while I am setting the `base_url` in `config.php` file to `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeig303';` and when i print it then it prints `localhost/codeig303/` but when i use it in `href` then it repeat the url like `localhost/codeig303/localhost/codeig303/`, and if I set it to `$config['base_url'] = '';` then it returns `http://::1/codeig303/`.

but it was working in codeigniter 3.0.1 i was using before

Comment: What about this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/';`

Comment: it works for url, but now it doesn't know the functions inside controller. inside my controller i have a function that loads a view, but it says the URL 'project/controller/function' was not found on this server

Comment: most likely your htaccess on main directory

Comment: try $config['base_url'] = false

Comment: thanks wolfgang1983 it works now

Answer (score 5):

add `http:` before `localhost`
, instead of

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeig303';
```

add this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeig303/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeated time show the localhost/codeig303/localhost/codeig303/ URL

pls add http:// for front of localhost

like http://localhost/codeig303

If you apply this type, then working fine.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
 <a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>your/directory">Something</a>
```

also

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeig303';
```

should be:

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeig303/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to config.php:

```
if(ENVIRONMENT != 'production')
$config['base_url'] = (is_https() ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])));
else $config['base_url'] = '';
```

and Add `<?php echo base_url(); ?>/'your file locations'`

Hope this Answer your question..!

Answer (score 0):

In localhost keep `base_url()` empty. When you upload to live server then add `base_url()` as `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

**.htaccess** (outside application folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

[Codeigniter URLs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: load url helper as well

Comment: @barakataliforoz did you check this??

Comment: According to the CI [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_303.html#step-2-make-sure-your-base-url-config-value-is-not-empty) in v3.0.3 the 'base_url' config should NOT be empty.

Comment: you need to make it empty on live server, lets say your website is "www.something.com" but if someone uses "something.com" and the `base_url` is set to `www.something.com` there will be problems. same goes with `http` and `https` , you also have to make a 301 redirection.

Comment: When there is https i have another answer. But i think that not suit for this. Any way thanx @Dray

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to autoload.php:

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

base url add with http or https
like - **$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeig303/';
also check url header load or not.**