# Form action in Codeigniter 3 6

Tags: forms, codeigniter, action, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter3.0.6, and i cont set the form action proper, when i submit the form it goes directly to localhost home page, my code is bellow
i set the `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/consultant';` because without it the base url return was like `http://::1/consultant` acording [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653906/base-url-is-not-working-in-codeigniter-3-0-3)

My view

```
<form role="form" action="<?=base_url();?>login/auth" method="post" class="login-form" id="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="formusername form-control" id="form-username">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
    </form>
```

I used the `base_url('login/auth')` and `site_url('login/auth');` when I do inspect element, it shows the correct url like `http://localhost:8081/consultant/login/auth` , but application goes to the localhost home page.

Comment: add your controller code of auth function

Comment: Can you explain me more

Comment: If the URL is correct, then what about your routes?  You need to setup the routing in your `routes.php` configuration file.  Read the manual:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found my answer. In Codeigniter 2 the htaccess file RewriteRule was like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but in Codeigniter 3 you need to put your project name before index.php. for example mine is: "consultant"

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /consultant/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and remember that you set your base_url like bellew:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'protocol://localhost/projectname';
```

mine is like below:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/consultant';
```

and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your htaccess file?
if not, you need to use

```
<form action="<?= base_url('index.php/login/auth')?>" method="post">
```

if yes you are right

```
<form action="<?= base_url('login/auth')?>" mehtod="post">
```

htaccess file as an example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /consultant/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /consultant/index.php
</IfModule>
```